# neo4j 120 seconds error after copying graph.db permission

Tags: neo4j, chmod

This is my problem. I have copied graph.db for a backup. 
Neo4j was started when I did that.

After that I deleted graph.db and neo4j started a new one. Neo4j is working fine, no problems. 
But when wanted to copy again graph.db (the backup one) I get:

```
 Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
 waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
```

I have uninstalled and installed again neo4j and it does not work.

I think is a problem of permissions... If yes how to solve it? I have tried to change permissions with chmod but it does not work... Someone can help me with the code for changing the permissions or configure neo4j with good permissions.

On the log: this appears multiple times:

```
2014-08-14 15:27:58.102+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
```

Any other suggestion?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I have seen precisely this behavior when I try to create a neo4j DB on a slow IO device.   I.e. sometimes if you tried to use neo4j-shell -path foo.db on an external USB drive, this would occur where it wouldn't occur if the DB was on a local disk or faster IO device.   Also, how are you "copying"?   Do you mean filesystem copy or what?

Comment: Since you made the backup copy of graph.db while neo4j was still running, I suspect that your backup is corrupted somehow. This would explain why neo4j is repeatedly trying (and failing) to recover from an "incorrectly shut down database", and eventually timing out. One should only copy the data *after* stopping neo4j. I am not sure how to recover from this.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits For copying I meant just open the path where the file graph.db was and right click copy and paste in another folder. It might be corrupted. Then I checked that for doing a backup I should do: what appears here [link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/backup-embedded-and-server.html)

Comment: can you try to run "bin/neo4j console" to see what actually happens and which errors are reported?

Comment: See @cybersam's answer, you must not copy the database while Neo4j is still running, you can easily end up with corrupted data.

Comment: I did an experiment with a new database from another computer (this time with ubuntu) I tried this: I created some nodes and relations, very few like 10 (the matrix example). Then I stopped the service neo4j. Then I copied the folder data that contains graph.db to another location. After that I deleted the graph.db folder and started neo4j. It created a new graph.db folder and the database runs as new, that is normal. Then I stopped again and paste the old graph.db. Same error as before. I tried pasting the data folder. Same error. How should I backup and restore in neo4j community offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented before the data was corrupted. It was impossible to recover it.

The correct way to do the backup is: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567744/backup-neo4j-community-edition-offline-in-unix-mac-or-linux)

- **Never** copy the files while running the database.
- We need to zip the graph.db file and then copy it in another location as a backup.
- For restore **stop the database** just delete recursively graph.db and unzip the backup.

Sadly the first data could not be restored...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
bin/neo4j start-no-wait
```

instead of

```
bin/neo4j start
```

Comment: I tried that. But it does not work. The strange thing is that it says that 120 seconds have passed but actually it has passed like 1 second only. Actually the data that I needed was available in my computer but I had to process all again and that took me hours, it was impossible to solve the problem of restoring the backup... Thanks for your answer it can be helpful for another person that has the problem of the 120 seconds