# Preproduction of web application on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are going to make public our first web application on Neo4j database and right now have a following questions:

1. How to properly backup embedded Neo4j database. Is there a standard mechanism for this purpose ? What is the best practice for that ?
2. How to properly move existing embedded Neo4j database to a new versions ?
3. In case of any further Neo4j database schema changes, how to properly apply it ? Is there any migrations mechanism for Neo4j ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A proper backup feature is available in Neo4j enterprise edition. Aside from creating backups while Neo4j is running it also does a very verbose consistency check of the backup to guarantee restorability. For community see [Backup neo4j community edition offline in unix: mac or linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567744/backup-neo4j-community-edition-offline-in-unix-mac-or-linux)
2. shut down the database, create a archive of `data/graph.db` and move that to the other machine.
3. use [Liquigraph](http://liquigraph.github.io/)