# How to save Graphs in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new Neo4j and I was wondering how to save a graph and upload it again. When I try to save my graph in either a CSV or JSON file it seems to only save the nodes and none of the relationships. I want to be able to completely save a graph and import the identical graph back with all the nodes and relationships intact.

Comment: How are you trying to save graph? Show us an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph itself is stored in the `graph.db` directory, which you can find in your neo4j data (2.x) or data/databases (3.x) sub-directories.

You can simply back-up that folder and later move/copy that back-up in the appropriate place, before starting up the neo4j server to get your graph back.

Comment: I can't seem to locate the graph.db directory. When I open up my Neo4j folder all it has is a default.graphdb folder. I'm not sure if the files inside the default.graphdb file represents my graph. It contains many files that begin with "neostore"

Comment: Why the downvote? That is exactly the folder I was talking about.

Comment: It wasn't me, I would upvote if I could. I just joined and have less than 15 reputation, so I can't vote.

Comment: Did you verify that backing up that folder works for you?

Comment: Yea,thank you! Also additional question, do you happen to know if I switch versions like from Neo4j 2.3 to Neo4j 3.0 is there a way to save the 2.3 graphs and use it in 3.0 by just copying the folder? When I tried copying the folder into my Neo4j 3.0 folder and loaded the graph it went back to Neo4j 2.3.

Comment: In your neo4j.conf, you want to have `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` (just remove the `#` symbol in that line... should be around line 23) to use a 2.3 graph.db in 3.x.

Comment: Ah thank you, the only problem is I can't seem to find neo4j.conf. Is there possibly another name it could be under, or am I searching in the wrong folder? I am in the default.graphdb one for clarification.

Comment: that file is in the `conf` folder

Comment: I have tried looking looking for my conf folder; however, I don't have any conf folder that belongs to Neo4j. I'm using a Mac if that helps.

Comment: what is the full path of your neo4j installation?

Comment: Ah, nevermind I found it, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If your problem is solved, please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by upload it again, but it sounds like you're referring to a backup of the database, and restoring from backup later.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569005) might be what you're looking for.

Otherwise, you might look at the [import/export options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569005) offered by the APOC procedures plugin.